# What is intelligent routing in terms of mircroservices and distributed systems?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

In the [introduction page of spring cloud](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/) it is said that

> Spring Cloud provides tools for developers to quickly build some of
>   the common patterns in distributed systems (e.g. configuration
>   management, service discovery, circuit breakers, ***intelligent routing***,
>   micro-proxy, control bus, one-time tokens, global locks, leadership
>   election, distributed sessions, cluster state)

In terms of microservices and distributed systems, can someone explain what intelligent routing is ?

Answer (score 1):

Intelligent routing in Spring Cloud refers to the [Zuul](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/wiki) project (see the [Spring Cloud Netflix guide](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/)). It uses reverse proxies: when you define a resource location in your public API, Zuul basically re-routes calls to these locations to your microservices. In effect, you can hide the locations and compositions of your microservices without changing your API.